# SharePoint Designer to calculate complex formulas for different list views

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have a custom list with different views. In each view I need calculated columns that span across the entire list. How do I use SharePoint designer to perform formula calculations in the views that would span entire view?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculated columns only work on the current row item.  To do aggregate across multiple rows, you're going to need to roll your own data view web part and create custom formulas in XSLT on the nodeset.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I followed this link and was able to do it. However, I couldn't get the sub total for each group and Total for the whole group. Must have been because of my immaturity with xslt/xpath. Just wondering if there's a way may be a browser Url that would help me see what xml is being returned by the data view web part would be helpful to me. Thanks.

Comment: This link might be useful to others looking for the same solution: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2011/01/sharepoint-group-by-on-more-than-2.html